# Android webview set (inject) WebBackForwardList

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am writing an Android browser, based on webview.
And after app is closed, I want to set history, saved in database, to webview, so it would display history (back stack) from previous sessions. But there is no such method. (we only have copyBackForwardList() method in WebView, that is all)

I tried to do it without goBack() method, just saving URL, which came to WebViewClient::onPageFinished() method, but this approach does not always work - for Facebook site, for example, I do not get any calls for WebViewClient methods, so one single tap back, would get previous site, before Facebook, and not, feed, (EXAMPLE: navigation path was: site -> fb feed -> feed detail). When the same is done with goBack() method it work just right (we go back to feed).
But again, no previous session's histories survives after app restart.

Please, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I applied the solution found in open source Lightning Browser.
The idea is to save and store the instance state bundle to file in onStop, and apply it back in on start.
That is hacky, but it worked !